# Draw a box at an angle

Tags: python, graphics, drawing, trigonometry

How can I change the code below so that drawRect also accepts an `angle` parameter?

`(x, y)` represents the centroid. As I think I understand it I would want to determine the coordinates of the four corners and then rotate all of them around `(x, y)` by that many degrees, keeping the same distance.

```
# draw a line from a to b
def line(a, b):
  # [code omitted]

def drawRect(x, y, w, h):
    a = (x - w / 2, y - h / 2)
    b = (x + w / 2, y - h / 2)
    c = (x + w / 2, y + h / 2)
    d = (x - w / 2, y + h / 2)
    line(a, b)
    line(b, c)
    line(c, d)
    line(d, a)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (and also not tested):

```
from math import cos, sin, pi
def drawRect(x, y, w, h, angle):
    x_vec = (cos(angle), sin(angle))
    y_vec = (cos(angle+pi/2.0), sin(angle+pi/2.0))
    a = (x - x_vec[0]*w/2 - y_vec[0]*h/2, y - x_vec[1]*w/2 - y_vec[1]*h/2)
    b = (x + x_vec[0]*w/2 + y_vec[0]*h/2, y - x_vec[1]*w/2 - y_vec[1]*h/2)
    c = (x + x_vec[0]*w/2 + y_vec[0]*h/2, y + x_vec[1]*w/2 + y_vec[1]*h/2)
    d = (x - x_vec[0]*w/2 - y_vec[0]*h/2, y + x_vec[1]*w/2 + y_vec[1]*h/2)
    line(a, b)
    line(b, c)
    line(c, d)
    line(d, a)
```

Comment: this seems right, and was more elegant than my solution. I forgot to account for the effects of the angle on height and width.

Comment: weird, I'm only getting right angles out of this... maybe I'm doing something else wrong though

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Were you expecting rectangles without right angles?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the problem down. Drawing the rectangle and rotating the points of the rectangle can be separate functions. By turning the rotation into a class you can avoid redundant calculations.

```
class rotate:
    def __init__(self, degrees):
        angle = math.radians(degrees)
        self.sin = math.sin(angle)
        self.cos = math.cos(angle)

    def pt(self, x, y):
        return x * self.cos + y * self.sin, y * self.cos - x * self.sin

def drawRect(x, y, w, h, degrees):
    rot = rotate(degrees)
    x1, y1 = rot.pt(-w / 2, -h / 2)
    a = x + x1, y + y1
    x2, y2 = rot.pt( w / 2, -h / 2)
    b = x + x2, y + y2
    x3, y3 = rot.pt( w / 2,  h / 2)
    c = x + x3, y + y3
    x4, y4 = rot.pt(-w / 2,  h / 2)
    d = x + x4, y + y4
    line(a, b)
    line(b, c)
    line(c, d)
    line(d, a)
```

Comment: this rotated the rectangles correctly but moved them far from their original position

Comment: it's rotating the points, but what point is it rotating them *around*?

Comment: @ʞɔıu the origin is (0,0). That's why I add the `x` and `y` after they've been rotated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `numpy`, as it allows for much more convenient array- and in this case matrix-calculations.

```
import numpy as np
```

At first you can define a rotation function, which accepts an angle in degree and returns the according rotation matrix:

```
def rot(phi):
  phi = np.deg2rad(phi)
  return np.array([[np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi)], [np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi)]])
```

Then you can add the rotation to your function like:

```
def drawRect(x, y, w, h, angle):
    a = np.array((-w / 2, -h / 2))
    b = np.array((w / 2, -h / 2))
    c = np.array((w / 2, h / 2))
    d = np.array((-w / 2, h / 2))
    if angle != 0:
        a = np.matmul(rot(angle), a)
        b = np.matmul(rot(angle), b)
        c = np.matmul(rot(angle), c)
        d = np.matmul(rot(angle), d)
    a += [x, y]
    b += [x, y]
    c += [x, y]
    d += [x, y]
    line(a, b)
    line(b, c)
    line(c, d)
    line(d, a)
```